# Angular2 - Call function from a tested component

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I'm currently writing unit tests for Angular2 with Karma and Jasmine, but I'm pretty new in the unit testing and I'm facing some difficulties. When it comes to testing hardcoded properties or properties that don't involve async functions, it's all okay, but I need to be able to call the component's functions in order for some variables to get their values. What I'm doing is the following:

My component:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

formLoginId: string;
loginUrl: string;
email: string;
password: string;

constructor(private googleAuthService: GoogleAuthService,
            private authService: AuthenticationService,
            private validationService: ValidationService,
            private router: Router,
            private titleService: Title) {
    this.titleService.setTitle("Login");
    this.formLoginId = "#form-login";
}

ngOnInit() {

    this.googleAuthService.getLink((response) => {
        this.loginUrl= response.json().url;
    });       
}

login() {
    if (this.validationService.isValid(this.formLoginId)) {
        this.authService.login(this.email, this.password);
    }
}
```

Now I want to write a unit test which can check if the loginUrl has taken any value. My test is bellow:

```
describe('Login Component', ()=> {
    let component:LoginComponent;
    let fixture:any;

    beforeEach(async(()=> {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            //declarations,imports and providers
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });   /some-other-tests/

    it('should have login url', fakeAsync(()=> {
        component.ngOnInit();
        tick(1000);
        expect(component.loginUrl).toBeDefined();
    }));
});
```

But it seems that its not working. I'm still getting undefined for the mentioned variable. How can I call a method from a component and check the variables after its result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you need to mock the GoogleAuthService to return with some information, as otherwise that getLink never resolves.

You can specify a mock provider for the GoogleAuthService and have it return an observable that's already resolved.